# Trying to add an attribute to all images

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not understanding what I am doing wrong, this is supposed to add contextmenu attribute to images to return false. I tried 'img[i].contextmenu="return false";' too.

```
var img = document.body.getElementsByTagName("img");
var i = 0;
while (i < img.length) {
    img[i].setAttribute("contextmenu", "return false;");
    i++;
}
```

I'm basically wanting to turn this jQuery into JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event attributes start with `on` so try

```
var img = document.body.getElementsByTagName("img");
var i = 0;
while (i < img.length) {
    img[i].setAttribute("oncontextmenu", "return false;");
    //img[i].oncontextmenu = function(){return false;};
    i++;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zT3Vu/)

Comment: not working i checked the DOM myself, plus got error on chrome (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier)

Comment: check this, its my website and try right clicking the checkmark images http://www.solocreations.org/

Comment: @Solo You have `ar img = document.body.getElementsByTagName("img");` in your script.

Comment: @Solo your page isn't loaded yet, so you will not find any images. Wait until the DOM is ready to call the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17655/discussion-between-solo-and-musa)